# "k ef migration add test" gives exception when using code first migrations in asp.net vNext

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure if this is supposed to work yet, but I couldn't find very much info about this.
I'm running the command

> k ef migration add test

In an attempt to enable migrations for my code first model. The exception I get is:

> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Next' in type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.SqlServer
>   .SequentialGuidValueGenerator' from assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version
>   =7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

This implies that this just isn't implemented yet, but I find that hard to believe. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

The project I use was created with VS2014 CTP3 and set to use the core CLR. This is the project.json:

```
{
"webroot" : "wwwroot",
"exclude": "wwwroot/**/*.*",
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SqlServer": "3.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Authentication": "3.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-alpha4",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-alpha4",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-*"
},
"commands": {
    /* Change the port number when you are self hosting this application */
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
     "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50" : { },
    "aspnetcore50" : { }
}
```

}

I thought that this could maybe a versioning problem, so I changed the EF reference to this:

> "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-*"

Which gives me this exception on the migrations command:

> System.Exception: TODO: No service for type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Migrations.ModelDiffer' has been registered.

Which I guess is a better exception to get, but I couldn't find anything on how to fix this. The available musicstore sample does not use migrations.

**UPDATE**

The context and model:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");

        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
        base.OnConfiguring(options);
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int MyModelId{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Setup configuration sources
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
        configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        // Set up application services
        app.UseServices(services =>
        {
            // Add EF services to the services container
            services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer();

            // Add MVC services to the services container
            services.AddMvc();
        });

        // Enable Browser Link support
        app.UseBrowserLink();

        // Add static files to the request pipeline
        app.UseStaticFiles();

    }
}
```

Maybe important, I'm running this on Windows 10 technical preview.

**Update 2**

Maybe important for versioning problems, my Nuget.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/" />
    <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <AspNetVNext>
      <add key="Username" value="aspnetreadonly" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="4d8a2d9c-7b80-4162-9978-47e918c9658c" />
    </AspNetVNext>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you share you `DbContext` class as well as any EF-related code in your `Startup.Configure()` method?

Comment: You shouldn't mix package versions. Change the version of `EntityFramework.Commands` to `7.0.0-alpha4` (or the others to `-*`).

Comment: Also, the ModelDiffer issue was fixed today (by [#904](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/904))

Comment: That's it.. changing all to -alpha4 solved it.